# Is there a way to get notified when your website crashes Chrome with "Aw snap!"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would like to be able to monitor whenever users of our website get the "Aw snap!" error. Is there a way in Chrome to get notified of these events via some type of JavaScript listener mechanism?

Comment: Somewhat you are looking for this:https://superuser.com/questions/607563/how-to-determine-what-is-causing-chrome-to-show-the-aw-snap-dialogue

Comment: @marcelo the link provided shows how to enable logging client-side, but this won't send the log to the webmaster (which is what the OP is asking) ; to answer the post, I don't know any mechanism available for that.

Answer (score 0):

### My solution

1. measure how much "came".

   - You can use something like AWS or google cloud to monitor the first click(on a search results page) count. so `first click count` = people came to your site. Or:
   - with a server:

     - Use some kind of landing page with a lower probablity of "Aw, snapping" and use it to send data to Google cloud or your server with a data "someone came" and add it to the `someone came count`. After that direct the user to the full page. so `someone came count` = people came to your site.
     - After loading the header and a small contain of your website, stop all other processes and send data to Google cloud or your server with a data "someone came" and add it to the `someone came count`. After that direct the user to the full page. so `someone came count` = people came to your site.
2. Count who did not have a "Aw, snap".

   - After loading all your sites dynamic and static content use a javascript function(or php) to send data to a google cloud or your server saying "this visit didn't have a "Aw, snap" and add it to the `non Aw,snap visits count`.
3. Find who had the "Aw, snap".

   - Substract `non Aw,snap visits count` from `someone came count`.

### Possible bloopers and improvements

Little worning for a blooper: There is a little probability of your landing page for the full page crashing or the first content loaded in your site crashing.

Improvements:
You can maybe send the user account and time and make a more informative record of the "Aw,snap" - get the permission anyway :).

### Notes for using

I am a newbie to the webmaster world so if someone can spot where a php functio is not good; js will be more stable or possible "ways of not be abe to do the above(s) please feel free to comment or edit.